# What is the meaning of $\;x\;dx=y\;dy\;$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that $x > y$ and $\;x\;dx=y\;dy.\;$

Can someone explain to me what is the meaning of this and how are x and y related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $x > y$ and $x \;dx = y\;dy$,

First, we can integrate both sides of the equation to get $$\int x\,dx = \int y\,dy \iff \dfrac {x^2}{2} + C_1= \dfrac{y^2}{2} + C_2 \quad C_1, C_2 \text{ constants}$$ $$\implies x^2 - y^2 = 2(C_2 - C_1) = k$$

Clearly, $k > 0$ since $x> y$.

For any given $k$, the set of ordered pairs $(x, y)$ that satisfy $x^2 - y^2 = k$ is an hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks amWhy. Can you tell me what's the explanation of $xdx=ydy$ itself? More precise, what's the meaning of $xdx$? Then what does it mean if two equation of this form are equal?

Comment: @pooya $xdx=ydy$ is a simple differential equation, derived by differentiating the equation $x^2=y^2+c$, where c is an arbitrary constant. Also, $xdx$, means x multiplied by the differential of x(i.e. dx). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)